# .NET Core CLI command fails to create new app on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

After installing [.NET Core 3.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) on `Windows 10`, I followed [this Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/#net-core-30) to create a new simple `Hello World` console app using `.NET Core CLI` command. But I get the following `build error` **Question**: What I may be missing and how can we resolve it?

**Error**:

```
PS C:\tmp> dotnet new console
>> dotnet run
The template "Console Application" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on C:\tmp\tmp.csproj...
  Restore completed in 41.91 ms for C:\tmp\tmp.csproj.

Restore succeeded.

t.cs(1,27): error CS1002: ; expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(3,1): error CS1646: Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @ [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(3,2): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(4,21): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(4,23): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(5,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(7,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(7,2): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(7,4): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(7,11): error CS1031: Type expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(7,11): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(7,12): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(9,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(9,2): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(9,3): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(10,11): error CS1002: ; expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(10,11): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(10,12): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(10,18): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(10,39): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(10,39): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(10,42): error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(10,42): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(11,4): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(11,4): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(13,2): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(13,10): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(13,11): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(13,21): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(13,31): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(13,34): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(13,34): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(13,35): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(13,41): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(13,50): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(13,56): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(13,63): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<' [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(14,8): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<' [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(15,17): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(15,20): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(15,20): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(15,38): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(15,41): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(15,41): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(15,42): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(15,47): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(15,63): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<' [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(16,21): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(16,26): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(16,34): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '/' [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(16,42): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<' [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(17,10): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '/' [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(19,14): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(19,17): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(19,35): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(19,39): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(19,55): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<' [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(20,16): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(20,20): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(20,30): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(20,35): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(20,46): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '>' [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(20,47): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<' [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(21,6): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '/' [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(21,9): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '<' [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(23,8): error CS1026: ) expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(23,8): error CS1002: ; expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(23,13): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(23,13): error CS1514: { expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(23,13): error CS1513: } expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(23,13): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(24,6): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(24,8): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(25,10): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(25,12): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(26,19): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(26,40): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(26,40): error CS1026: ) expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(26,40): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(26,57): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(26,58): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(26,59): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(26,64): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(27,11): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(27,13): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(28,10): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(28,12): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(29,19): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(29,40): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(29,40): error CS1026: ) expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(29,40): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(29,57): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(29,58): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(29,59): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(29,64): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(30,11): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(30,13): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(31,10): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(31,12): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(32,19): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(32,40): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(32,40): error CS1026: ) expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(32,40): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(32,57): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(32,58): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(32,59): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(32,70): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(33,11): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(33,13): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(34,10): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(34,12): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(35,19): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(35,40): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(35,40): error CS1026: ) expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(35,40): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(35,57): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(35,58): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(35,59): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(35,64): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(36,11): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(36,13): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(37,7): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(37,9): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(38,6): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(38,11): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(39,27): error CS1026: ) expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(39,50): error CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(39,51): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(39,52): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(39,54): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(39,55): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(41,14): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(41,16): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(42,18): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(42,20): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(43,27): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(43,39): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(43,39): error CS1026: ) expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(43,39): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(43,56): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(43,57): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(43,58): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(43,63): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(44,19): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(44,21): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(45,18): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(45,20): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(46,27): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(46,39): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(46,39): error CS1026: ) expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(46,39): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(46,56): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(46,57): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(46,58): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(46,63): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(47,19): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(47,21): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(48,18): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(48,20): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(49,27): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(49,39): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(49,39): error CS1026: ) expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(49,39): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(49,56): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(49,57): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(49,58): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(49,69): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(50,19): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(50,21): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(51,18): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(51,20): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(52,27): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(52,39): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements. [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(52,39): error CS1026: ) expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(52,39): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(52,56): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(52,57): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(52,58): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(52,63): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(53,19): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(53,21): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(54,15): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(54,17): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(55,9): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(56,5): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(56,7): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(56,12): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(57,3): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(57,8): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(58,29): error CS1002: ; expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(58,34): error CS1001: Identifier expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(58,34): error CS1514: { expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(58,34): error CS1513: } expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(58,34): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(58,58): error CS1031: Type expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(58,58): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(58,59): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(59,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(59,3): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]
t.cs(59,7): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [C:\tmp\tmp.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
PS C:\tmp>
```

Comment: was the folder empty you ran this command in?

Comment: @MartinUllrich No. The folder `C:\tmp` has many other files and folders. Probably that's the cause of the error.

Comment: @MartinUllrich You got it. Your comment resolved the issue - after I ran the command on a newly created empty folder. You may want to convert your comment to a `Response` and I'll mark it as an `Answer` for the benefit of other readers.